# How to change dash size in 13.04?

Tags: unity, 13.04, unity-dash

It appears that support had been dropped for configuring the dash size in the latest Unity release, and now the *Desktop* option has no effect (i.e. *Netbook* size is always used).

Just to illustrate, this is what I get regardless of the screen size or the configuration:

[image: dash-netbook-size]

---

I have tried to set it via Ubuntu Tweak, like so (see *Dash size*):

[image: ubuntu-tweak]

And the Unity Tweak Tool is already ignoring that option altogether:

[image: unity-tweak-tool]

What's more, the *form-factor* entry is missing from dconf-editor:

[image: dconf-editor]

I really like **a.** having the dash spreading on my entire desktop, and **b.** being able to configure it (!). ***Is it really gone***?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that 13.04 has moved to Unity 3D out-of-the-box, hence no 2D features (like *Dash size*) are available.

The only way, than, to change the dash layout would be to maximize / restore it via the window handles on top:

[image: dash-maximized]

Comment: good it didnt bite me, thx :)

Comment: that is the last place I would have looked.